# Iterating through map C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a map that is storing components of a polynomial. The key is the exponent and the value is the coefficient.The map that has integer keys and integer values. I am iterating in my print function, the program crashes when I do my iteration. As I was putting keys into my arrays everything seemed to check out. The input file has this format -1 0 5 1 20 3 -9 2 -2 1 1 2 -2 3 1 9,where every pair is (coefficient, exponent).`

```
//header
#ifndef poly_h
#define poly_h
#include <map>
class poly {

private:
    std::map<int, int>* pol;

public:
    poly(char* filename);
    poly& operator+(poly& rhs);
    poly& operator-(poly& rhs);
    poly& operator*(poly& rhs);
    void print();
    ~poly();
};
#endif
```

```
//cpp file
#include "poly.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
poly::poly(char* filename)
{

    map<int, int>* pol = new map<int, int>;
    ifstream input_file;
    input_file.open("input.txt");
    int coe;
    int exp;

    while (input_file >> coe) {
        input_file >> exp;
        cout << coe << " ^" << exp << " ";
        map<int, int>::iterator it = pol->find(exp);
        if (it == pol->end()) {
            (*pol)[exp] = coe;
        }
        else {
            (*pol)[exp] += coe;
            if ((*pol)[exp] == 0) {
                pol->erase(it);
            }
        }
        cout << (*pol)[exp];
        //print();
        cout << endl;
    }
    input_file.close();
}
void poly::print()
{
    cout << "inside print<<endl;                                                                   
        for (map<int, int>::iterator outer_iter = pol->begin(); outer_iter != pol->end(); ++outer_iter);
    cout << "done";
}
poly::~poly()
{
    delete pol;
}
```

Comment: `std::map<int,int> *pol;` -- There is no need for this to be a pointer, and then later on use `new` and `delete`.  All you need is `std::map<int, int> pol;`.  Also, can you clean up the formatting?  It's all over the place, making it hard to read your code.

Comment: Also, please post a [mcve], which means a `main` function.  The reason is that I can easily break your program (all due to the pointer I mentioned) with a simple 2 or 3 line program.  Also, operator+, -, and * should be returning a new `poly` object, not a reference.

Comment: cout << (*pol)[exp];

I think that's gonna break if the value becomes 0, because you erase a few lines above.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Next time I'll definitely have better formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
map<int, int>* pol = new map<int, int>;
```

is the culprit. It creates a function local variable. It does not set the value of the member variable. As a consequence, the member variable of the same name remains uninitialized. Dereferencing that variable in other functions causes undefined behavior.

Change that line to:

```
pol = new map<int, int>;
```

---

As was suggested in one of the comments, I would strongly advise changing that member variable from a pointer to an object. You get automatic memory management from using an object. You don't need to worry about using `new` to allocate memory for it and using `delete` to deallocate memory used by it. Not only that, if you take on the job of allocating memory in your class, you need to know about [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and make sure your class confirms to those rules.

If you are using a C++11 compiler, [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) becomes the [The Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11).

Comment: In GCC you can turn on: -Wshadow  That should warn you in this situation.

Comment: For C++11, the rule of three became a rule of five.  That becomes a rule of zero for (among other things) classes that don't explicitly manage a resource (e.g. if `pol` becomes a `map<int, int>` rather than a pointer to one).